# Displaying a default image and changing it once the actual image finished loading

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, bitmapimage, markup-extensions

I have a WPF markup extension in charge of retrieving images by name, returning a `BitmapImage` object.

```
<Image Source="{my:ImageProvider ImageName=myImageName}"></Image>
```

Since retrieving an image is an operation that can possibly take a few seconds, I'd like to show a default image and display the requested image once it's ready.

What I tried to do is something like this, but as this may change the `BitmapImage` object, it won't update the UI (sample code):

```
BitmapImage img;
public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"D:\defaultImage.png", UriKind.Absolute));

    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();

    return img;
}

void bw_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
}

void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    img.UriSource = new Uri(@"D:\actualImage.png", UriKind.Absolute);
}
```

Is there a way I can update the UI to use the modified `BitmapImage` (something like INotifyPropertyChanged) or is there a different approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with two ways to do this. Both ways use a class that wraps the image and implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
class ImageSourceWrapper : ObservableObject
{
    private ImageSource _image;
    public ImageSource Image
    {
        get { return _image; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _image)
            {
                _image = value;

                RaiseOnPropertyChanged("Image");
            }
        }
    }

    public ImageSourceWrapper(ImageSource image)
    {
        Image = image;
    }
}
```

### First Approach

Once I have this, I can have my markup extension return an `ImageSourceWrapper` object and bind to it, like so

```
<Image Source="{Binding Source={my:ImageProvider ImageName=myImageName}, Path=Image}" />
```

I didn't really like this way, since it's pretty messy and involves having to know the `ImageSourceWrapper` class rather than working simply with `ImageSource`. Then I came up with the second approach.

### Second Approach

In this approach I still use the `ImageSourceWrapper` class, but instead of having my markup extension return an `ImageSourceWrapper` object, I return a binding object which I set up to be bound to an `ImageSourceWrapper` object.

The markup extension looks something like this:

```
private ImageSourceWrapper _imageSourceWrapper;
public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    // Get the object and the property to be bound.
    IProvideValueTarget service = IProvideValueTarget)provider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget));
    DependencyObject targetObject = service.TargetObject as DependencyObject;
    DependencyProperty targetProperty = service.TargetProperty as DependencyProperty;

    // Set up the binding with the default image.
    _imageSourceWrapper = new ImageSourceWrapper(DefaultImage);
    Binding binding = new Binding("Image");
    binding.Source = _imageSourceWrapper;
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(targetObject, targetProperty, binding);

    // Retrieve the actual image asynchronously.
    GetImageAsync();

    return binding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
}

private void GetImageAsync()
{
    // Get the image asynchronously.

    // Freeze the image so it could be accessed from all threads regardless
    // of which thread it was created on.
    newImage.Freeze();

    // Got the image - update the _imageSourceWrapper object.
    _imageSourceWrapper = newImage;
}
```

Then I can use it in XAML like this

```
<Image Source="{my:ImageProvider ImageName=myImageName}" />
```

This way the default image is displayed first, and once the requested image is retrieved, it will be displayed instead.

*Sorry if the code here isn't entirely correct, I'm not near the code at the moment. Hopefully this is enough at the moment to express the main idea.*

Answer (score 1):

`PriorityBinding` is what you might be looking for i guess.
You can bind to two different DP's with your actual image source as the highest binding and not forgot to set `IsAsync` property to true for that binding.
Once, your image source is ready it will automatically replaced the second binding.

Refer to this link to get started - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.prioritybinding.aspx